# Drawable folder picking when building an application in android

Tags: android, drawable, dpi

I am developing an Android application in which I have resources in

`drawable-sw360dp-xhdpi` and `drawable-sw800dp-xhdpi`

When I ran the application(in 360dp device) the resources are picked from both these folders and are present in the final apk. I was getting no compile time errors in eclipse.

But, when I am opening the application(at runtime), the resources which are present in `800dp` folder are causing problems, saying

`inflateexception binary xml file error inflating class <unknown>`

Only when I copy the resources from `800dp` folder to `360dp` folder the exception was not coming. Even when I extracted the apk also, both these folders were present.

Why is this exception coming and why both the folders were present in the final apk?

Comment: does the names of the resources are same in both the folders

Comment: No, actually some resources are not there in `360dp` folder, but present in `800dp` folder. No, compile errors were coming and when i run the application, the exception mentioned was coming for files which were in `800dp` but not in `360dp`.

Comment: why you are not keeping those files in 360dp ,because when you run your app,resources are taken from 360dp and as they are  not present there your are facing errors

Comment: Yes exactly, but according to the android dev site, we can have that way. Android resizes the drawables according to the dpi of the device. If copy unnecessarily, the apk size also increases. Even in this case no compile errors are also coming. But, I am not getting why the exception is coming ?

Comment: is there any xml in drawable or may be there is some issue in layout, have you used same layout for both

Comment: Oh sorry, actually I was having the same layout for both kind of devices in 800dp folder. That is why it was picking the layout and its drawbles as well. Missed a basic thing. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MeenalSharma Better you can answer the question instead of commenting. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have used same layout for both, because of which it is giving error ,just check your layout or name of the resources used.